# using semaphores for a traffic synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, semaphore

I am trying to code for a traffic synchronization problem.
My approach is :

1. i am dividing the square for the traffic into 4 quadrants and I have implemented 4 threads for east-west-north-south directions from which a vehicle might approach the square.
2. Any vehicle approaching the square will get an exclusive lock on the quadrant and others will wait till this vehicle passes the square.
3. I am using semaphores for the solution. Pasting my code here :

This is my main class :

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThreadClass t1 = new MyThreadClass();
        Thread east = new Thread(t1, "east");
        Thread west = new Thread(t1, "west");
        Thread north = new Thread(t1, "north");
        Thread south = new Thread(t1, "south");

        east.start();
        west.start();
        north.start();
        south.start();
    }}
```

and other file which implements semaphore is :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MyThreadClass implements Runnable {

    Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1, true);
    String direction[] = {"left", "straight", "right"};
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int dirNo = generateRamdomNumberForDirection();
        String directionSelected = direction[dirNo];

        try
        {
            s.acquire();
            getLock(directionSelected , Thread.currentThread().getName());
            s.release();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ }
        //getLock(directionSelected);
    }

    private int generateRamdomNumberForDirection()
    {
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = direction.length;
        return Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) ));
    }

    private synchronized void getLock(String dir , String threadName)
    {
        switch(Thread.currentThread().getName())
        {
        case "east":
                if (dir.equals(direction[0]))
                {
                    System.out.println("lock on north east, north west and south west quadrant by east thread");
                }
                break;


        //TO BE IMPLEMENTED
        case "west":break;
        case "north":break;
        case "south":break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is I am getting a lock on all the 4 quadrants. I cannot find a solution if the vehicle wants to go straight. In that case only 2 quadrants will need a lock and a thread opposite to it can get lock on the rest to.

Is my approach to the problem  correct? 
Thanks

Comment: Two comments: First, you can use a plain old mutex (`Object` lock) instead of a semaphore. There's nothing particularly wrong with a semaphore here but semaphores are typically use when threads are waiting to access a pool of multiple resources -- in this case each quadrant is an independent single resource. Secondly (and I haven't looked through your code) when a vehicle is going straight, you're going to have to make sure that either a) if the vehicle can't obtain both quadrants, it obtains none, or b) the vehicle only holds one quadrant at a time. Your choice, but it will avoid gridlock.

Comment: As JasonC indicates, the quadrants are the "limited resource" here. The vehicles are the ones claiming the "limited resources". Typically, this means that the vehicles are the threads (or better: runnables) that want a lock on quadrant objects, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There will be four semaphores for each of quadrant on square.

```
     N
   1 | 2
W  ------ E
   3 | 4
     S
```

And four threads for vehicles coming for each side.

Each vehicle thread will generate random number(as you doing now) to decide which 
direction to turn(left, right, straight).

Depending on whether you are driving British style(drive on left) or American style(drive on right), acquire locks on respective quadrant semaphore.
e.g. you are going South to North: British style: acquire semaphore 3 then 1, American Style: acquire semaphore 4 then 2.

```
class LockOrder{
   List<Integer> leftTurn()
   List<Integer> rightTurn()
   List<Integer> straight()
}
```

create four objects LockOrder for each of direction vehicle is coming from.